# Converter segundos em minutos

Tags: php, mysql

Na data base registra os segundos onlines de cada usuário, mas fica números do tipo(exemplo): 23631. Gostaria de converter estes números em minutos, como faço?

```
<?php
$userstats_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_st");
while($oi = mysql_fetch_assoc($userstats_a)){
?>

<?php echo $oi['OnlineTime']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Não seria só dividir por 60, visto que cada minuto é composto por 60 segundos?

Comment: divide por 60 ?!

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**exemplo ideone**](https://ideone.com/slFDQa)

```
<?php
$userstats_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_stats INNER JOIN users ON user_stats.id = users.id WHERE users.Rank <5 ORDER BY user_stats.OnlineTime DESC LIMIT 3");
while($userstats = mysql_fetch_assoc($userstats_a)){
?>

<?php echo $userstats['OnlineTime']/60; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

> se quiser somente a parte inteira:

```
<?php echo (int)($userstats['OnlineTime']/60); ?>
```

> o resto da divisão

```
<?php echo ($userstats['OnlineTime'] % 60); ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado era bem simples :s

Answer (score 5):

Basta dividir por 60, e terá o tempo em minutos.
Na query, pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    (OnlineTime/60) as minutos
FROM user_stats 
INNER JOIN users ON user_stats.id = users.id 
WHERE users.Rank <5 
ORDER BY user_stats.OnlineTime DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo!